# How to make wix bundle delay starting of execution of a MSiPackage for the completion of an ExePackage

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

In my wix bundle I have two ExePackages and an MsiPackage. I need to start the installation of MsiPackage only after the complete execution of the Exepackage.

How can I make some delay in the MsiPackage execution in order to achieve this? Is there any other way to do this in Chain element?

Comment: You should say what the exepackage is.. Some of them (such as InstallShield-generated) have a command line option that makes the initiating process wait for the child process that does the actual install  to complete, which might be the issue.

Comment: My Exepackage is an Installshield exe. Do you have any idea about this? The execution of installshield exe is beyond my control. And it affects my upgrade case as it's not getting installed during upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield setups (such as setup.exe) fire off a child process to do the install, so the setup.exe process terminates with the install still running.

According to the documentation here:

http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm

there are a couple of choices, /SMS and /w so try those.

Comment: Yes, I used the /SMS flag years ago, but they say it is no longer needed. However, I had a problem with a **setup.exe** exiting early for a java package many years ago, as far as I recall it was an InstallAnywhere package of some kind. We weren't allowed to repackage so we ended up writing a VBScript that periodically checked the system for the presence of the installation log file (which was created at the end of the install). Barely acceptable if you ask me. All the crazy things we do to get broken deployment to work...

Comment: Anyway product delivered by blocking upgrade case. I will check this for the next delivery. Thank you.

Comment: If the InstallShield setup is old it might still use that older command line, if "no longer needed" applies only to recent versions of InstallShield.